# Android: images laid out in grid, and 4-way navigation

Tags: android, layout

I would like to do something like in the sketch.

[image: sketch]

Grid of 9 images, every image size fits screen size, user can move grid in up, down, left, right (with snap). Something like ViewPager in all directions.

How to achive this behaviour in Android?

In future there will be more images, so solution should manage memory in order to don't get OutOfMemory.

Comment: I don't know if it could work, but there are some vertical view pager out there. You could use 3 vertical view pager that contains each one view pager for each row and you would in theory get something like this...

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267763/android-four-directional-navigation