# Android large scrollable canvas

Tags: android, canvas, scroll

I want to make a large scrollable canvas where I would like to put some buttons which can be viewed by scrolling on the screen [image]

as you can see in the image, only two buttons are available at a time, but other buttons can be viewed by panning on the screen. Any suggestions to implement such interface on Android would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try checking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267763/android-four-directional-navigation) question. Looks fine but I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I checked the code and it is working nicely for directional swipe gestures (left, right, top and bottom). Instead of using directional swipe gesture, I am looking for continuous gestures to pan the entire canvas.